# Normal for my 401k to be performing at -11% over the past 18 months?

Tags: 401k, financial-literacy

Me:

- 27 years old
- Income of upper $70ks
- Contribute 6% to 401k, and 3% to roth 401k (increase my 401k by 1% each year; employer matches up to I think 3%)

Performance:

- Over the past 18 months, my Schwab account is showing a performance of **-11%**

I just want to make sure this is the normal up-and-down that I can expect, or should I evaluate my options more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's been a rocky year. If your 401(k) is diversified (as it should be) it should generally follow inflation and industry averages (except outperforming them slightly in the longterm). For example, take a look at the Dow Jones Industrial Average:

[image]

- it's down by 5% over the past 6 months.

...so I'd be worried if your 401(k) *did increase* in value over the past year, because that would mean it isn't diversified.

My own 401(k) is down -8% compared to 2 years ago.

My personal opinion is the market will not improve much (if at all) over the coming year either.

Comment: The text of your answer is pretty sound, but the factoid you offered, down 5% over last 6 months, is not quite correct. Up over 5% or so if you include dividends.

Comment: Not sure the final paragraph/sentence is really appropriate for the answer.  It's speculation on the market, which isn't something that is appropriate to an otherwise factual-based answer.

Comment: @Joe I didn't want the OP to go away with the impression his concerns will be allayed and that things are going to improve any time soon.

Comment: @Dai Well, you could've done that with a sentence noting that the market could continue to change... that sentence, though, is a predictive one.